# OSX ML Terminal - Switching tabs

Tags: macos, terminal

I am a terminal junkie and use it all the time...literally. Is there any way to be able to switch between tabs with Command+Number (eg. Command+1 for tab 1).

Yes, I know about iTerm, I'm just wondering if its possible to do this with stock terminal, since I am quite fond of it.

Thanks

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166695/is-it-possible-to-select-a-specific-tab-in-osx-terminal-app-using-keyboard-short

Answer (score 2):

You can move left and right through tabs with CMD + SHIFT + ] for right and CMD + SHIFT + [ for left.

Not necessarily choosing  exactly which tab.

Comment: I already know this, and its not what I want. Guess Ill have to switch to iterm after all.

Comment: I've switched to iTerm 2 and now OSX terminal feels like joke. <3 iTerm!